# Overloading Multiply Two Numbers

Tags: operator-overloading

Write a java class that has separate methods to multiply two numbers of different data types. This class should share the same name for the different methods which are adding two numbers of differnt data types

This class should have some methods so that you can add two

Integer numbers
Float & integer
Integer & float
Double & integer
Integer & double 
Float & double
Double & float
Double & double 
Float & float
 with the same name

All above methods should accept two parameters (of different data types and should return the answer
after that write a proper driver class to test all the methods

hint: use method over loading techniques

Comment: You should try to ask research oriented question.

Comment: this looks like a homework question.